# Library Workbook - I'm Trying To Edit The Stock Count On A File, But I Don't Know How

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct Book
{
    string titleofbook, authorofbook;
    int isbnno{}, copiesinventory{}, copieslent{};
};

main()
{
    int y, newamount, c=4;
    Book bookshere[c];
    ifstream read;
    read.open("bookdatabase.txt");
    string replace;


for(y=0; y<c; y++)
    {
        read>>bookshere[y].isbnno;
        read.ignore();
        getline(read, bookshere[y].titleofbook);
        getline(read, bookshere[y].authorofbook);
        read>>bookshere[y].copiesinventory;
        read>>bookshere[y].copieslent;
        read.ignore();
    };
    
    cout<<"\n"<<c<<endl;
    cout<<"===================";
    cout<<"\n LIBRARY INVENTORY\n";
    cout<<"===================\n\n";
    cout<<"ISBN NO.\t\tTITLE\t\tAUTHOR\t\t\tINVENTORY TOTAL\t\tCOPIES BORROWED\n";
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    for(y=0; y<c; y++)
        {
            cout<<setw(20)<<left<<bookshere[y].isbnno;
            cout<<setw(50)<<left<<bookshere[y].titleofbook;
            cout<<setw(20)<<left<<bookshere[y].authorofbook;
            cout<<setw(20)<<left<<bookshere[y].copiesinventory;
            cout<<setw(20)<<left<<bookshere[y].copieslent<<"\n";
        };

    ifstream append;
    append.open("bookdatabase.txt");
     
    for(y=0; y<c; y++)
        {
        append>>bookshere[y].isbnno;
        append.ignore();
        getline(append, bookshere[y].titleofbook);;
        getline(append, bookshere[y].authorofbook);
        append>>bookshere[y].copiesinventory;
        append>>bookshere[y].copieslent;
        append.ignore();
        };
    
    cout<<"\nENTER TITLE OF BOOK : ";
    getline(cin, replace);

        //fstream

        for(y=0; y<c; y++)
        {
            read>>bookshere[y].isbnno;
            read.ignore();
            getline(read, bookshere[y].titleofbook);;
            getline(read, bookshere[y].authorofbook);
            read>>bookshere[y].copiesinventory;
            read>>bookshere[y].copieslent;
            read.ignore();
        }
        
        //bookshere[y].copieslent=bookshere[y].copieslent+1;
        //newamount=bookshere[y].copieslent;
        
        cout<<"\n\nISBN NO.\t\tTITLE\t\tAUTHOR\t\t\tINVENTORY TOTAL\t\tCOPIES BORROWED\n";
        cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        for(y=0; y<c; y++)
            {
            if(bookshere[y].titleofbook==replace)
            {
            bookshere[y].copieslent=bookshere[y].copieslent+1;
            newamount=bookshere[y].copieslent;
            
            cout<<setw(20)<<left<<bookshere[y].isbnno;
            cout<<setw(50)<<left<<bookshere[y].titleofbook;
            cout<<setw(20)<<left<<bookshere[y].authorofbook;
            cout<<setw(20)<<left<<bookshere[y].copiesinventory;
            cout<<setw(20)<<left<<bookshere[y].copieslent<<"\n";
            
            
            }
        }
    
}
```

I just figured out formatting and the like. However, I have no idea as to how to edit the stock count on the books I have. The BORROWED BOOKS count should go up when you borrow a book, but I have no idea as to how to write the lines that would allow me to do so.

WHAT I TRIED

- Every YouTube video on file-handling known to man.
- basic "read and replace", but it wipes the whole file

Comment: Please do not joke about self-harm / suicide. It's irrelevant to the question and entirely inappropriate. I have removed those statements. If it's not a joke, please talk to a health professional.

Comment: Please show an example of your input file `"bookdatabase.txt"` (at least 10 lines or so). The mixed input you are doing on `read` with `>>`, `.ignore()` and `getline()` looks problematic. (if not it is certainly unorthodox)

Comment: Did you mean to open `append` in `std::ios::app` mode? See [std::basic_ofstream::open](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open)

Comment: Running your code on a 4-book input file -- your code does read and does increment the borrowed count (you can see that in what it outputs to the screen). The problem you are having with it wiping your file is you are not opening the file in append mode. That said, you should not use "YouTube" videos as a reference -- it's not and videos are flat wrong many many times. [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com) is the reference to use. You can't use `Book bookshere[c];`, that is a VLA which C++ only supports by non-standard extension. `std::vector<Book> bookshere{};` makes much more sense.

Comment: Since `Book` is part of a collection of books, it would make sense to wrap your `struct Book` in a class (say `Collection`). You can overload `>>` and `<<` so you read and write your collection with a simple `std:cout << bookshere;` and read the entire file by passing the open file-stream to the constructor. Your vector of Book holds all changes made during your session, then you write all books back out when done. (overwriting the original file). Never try and update part of a file in-place -- that never ends well. Read all lines with `getline` and use `std::stoi()` for integer conversion.

Comment: There isn't a lot to salvage in what you have, the reason being you wouldn't want to use an array of struct for storing you books. Highly inflexible making it impossible to add books. I backed out your input file format from what you have and rewrote you code at [ISBN Book Inventory](https://paste.opensuse.org/35b6c3c93884) (good for 30 days). It has the datafile used at the bottom. The `std::setw()` width are determined by max title/author size. Usage is `./program datafile (newdatafile)` where if no 2nd argument is given the updated inventory is written to the original filename.